# Check is even ngFor angular 4

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework

I have the bellow code to display two images in a single row.but the checking `*ngIf="even"` was not working .What is wrong with this?

```
 <div *ngFor="let narative_image of narative_images;let i = index;">
       <ion-row *ngIf="even" >
           <ion-col>
             <img  style="width: 100%; height: auto;"   src="{{narative_image[i].thumbimg}}" />
           </ion-col>
           <ion-col>
              <img  style="width: 100%; height: auto"  src="{{narative_image[i+1].thumbimg}}" />
           </ion-col>
       </ion-row>
   </div>
```

Comment: You haven't defined even anywhere. https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables

Comment: Please refer the following answers:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36375686/ngfor-using-ngclass-on-rows-and-columns-issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36375686/ngfor-using-ngclass-on-rows-and-columns-issue)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define 'even'

```
<div *ngFor="let n of narative_images;let i = index; let even = even">
```

More info [here](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-ngfor/).