# ngFor: different color for odd/even rows when loop is in ng-container

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have a table in which I'd like to give the odd and even rows a different background color. Normally, you can use the `odd` and `even` variables for this. However, I'm now building up my table rows inside an `ng-container` so I can conditionally create one or more rows per iteration. In this case, every iteration creates 1 or 2 rows, depending on a variable.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let detailof data.details; let odd = odd;">
    <tr [ngClass]="{ 'k-alt': odd}">
        <td>
            {{ detail.number1 }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ detail.number2 }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ detail.number3 }}
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr *ngIf="detail.conditionalVariable" [ngClass]="{ 'k-alt': odd}">
        <td></td>
        <td>{{ detail.conditionalVariable }}</td>
        <td></td>

    </tr>
</ng-container>
```

As you can see, every iteration will cause the rows to be marked with a different background and not every row itself because the odd variable is declared in the `*ngFor` in the `ng-container` element.

Is there a way to give each row a different background color when using `ng-container` with conditional rows?

Comment: you required each row with different color?

Comment: Yes, all odd rows in a certain color, all even rows in another certain color.

Comment: please attach image with diff color as you request, so we have better idea

Comment: Comparable to this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfRhR.jpg

Comment: attached image is odd, even color and that you have already done.

Comment: No, because when 2 records are created (when conditionalVariable is true), both of them will be counted as either odd or even...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the index property:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let detailof data.details; let index = index" [ngClass]="{'myStyle': 0 === index % 2}">...</ng-container>
```

[ngForOF Official docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf)

Comment: This worked for me, but it is worthy to note that adding ```[ngClass]``` to ```<ng-container>```, will likely bring an ```(cannot read property 'remove' of undefined)``` ERROR.

Comment: Please try this below link I think it's better than dividing with 2 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36375686/ngfor-using-ngclass-on-rows-and-columns-issue

Answer (score 23):

Why don't you use CSS for this? For example, set `k-alt` class for all of your rows and in your CSS:

```
tr.k-alt:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #CCC;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You can also use in this way:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let detail of data.details; let odd = odd">
    <tr [class.oddBackground]=" odd ">
        <td>
            {{ detail.number1 }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ detail.number2 }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ detail.number3 }}
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr *ngIf="detail.conditionalVariable" [ngClass]="{ 'k-alt': odd}">
        <td></td>
        <td>{{ detail.conditionalVariable }}</td>
        <td></td>

    </tr>
</ng-container>
```

This will add oddBackground class only if the row is odd which means odd variable is true.

Comment: Good answer for `ngFor` but use `[ngClass]="{'odd': odd}"`

Answer (score 8):

**UPDATE (for latest Angular versions):**

You can implement it like this:
`odd as isOdd; even as isEven;"`

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let detail of data.details; odd as isOdd; even as isEven;">

   <tr [ngClass]="{ 'odd': isOdd, 'even': isEven }">   // Or 'k-alt': isOdd
     ...
   </tr>

</ng-container>
```

Attached herewith is a **[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngfor-even-odd?file=src/app/app.component.ts)** for your reference.

---

You can also visit the **[NgForOf Documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf)** where it also supports e.g `first, last, and count`

Answer (score 2):

### Use *ngFor's "even" | "odd" properties!

No need to create css classe. All you need is html and Angular!

```
    <tr
      *ngFor="let row of data; even as isEven"
      [ngStyle]="{ background: isEven ? 'lightblue' : 'white' }"
    >
      // ...
    
    </tr>
```

Use this approach to get your rows colored in an lean and declarative way

Here is a full example:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th *ngFor="let headerItem of ['description', 'value', 'year']">
      {{ headerItem }}
    </th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr
      *ngFor="let row of data; even as isEven"
      [ngStyle]="{ background: isEven ? 'lightblue' : 'white' }"
    >
      <td>{{ row.description }}</td>
      <td>{{ row.value | currency }}</td>
      <td>{{ row.year }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[image: table with toggling row background-colors]